# Extending homotopies to contract an ascending union of contractible spaces

Tags: general-topology

I want to extend a continuous map $H\colon X×[0..1) → X$ to a homotopy $X×[0..1] → X$ by setting $H\lvert X×[1] → X$ as the projection to $X$ (put otherwise, $H_1 = \mathrm{id}_X$).

I have that

- $X$ is the union of an ascending chain of subspaces $X^0 ⊂ X^1 ⊂ …$ (where $X^0$ is a singleton),
- $X$ carries the final topology with respect to all inclusions $X^n ⊂ X$, and that
- for each $n$, the restricted homotopy $H\lvert_{X^n×[\frac{n}{n+1}..1]}$ is the projection onto $X^n$ (or put differently, $H$ is the identity on $X^n$ from the moment $1 - \frac{1}{n+1}$ on).

> How can I prove that this extension is continuous?

I encountered this problem while trying to prove that the union of an ascending chain of contractible deformation retracts $X^0 ⊂ X^1 ⊂ …$ is itself again contractible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functor $I\times-:\mathbf{Top}\to\mathbf{Top}$ is a left adjoint (where $I=[0,1]$), and thus commutes to colimits, so that
$$X\times I=(\mathrm{colim}_n\,X_n)\times I\simeq\mathrm{colim}_n\,(X_n\times I)$$
(See the [general exponential law](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+law+for+spaces#general_exponential_laws)).This tells you that a homotopy $H:X\times I\to Y$ is precisely the same thing as a family of homotopies $H_n:X_n\times I\to Y$ that agree where there is overlap.

So if the homotopies you already have agree on overlaps, then together they define a homotopy of maps $X\to X$.

**EDIT:** Iinitially wrote that $X$ should be assumed Hausdorff aswell, but that is unnecessary: as long as $S$ is locally compact Hausdorff, the map $S\times -$ is left adjoint to $(-)^S$, which is all you really need, so the fact that $I$ is locally compact Hausdorff is enough.

Comment: So, a homotopy $X × I → Y$ is *always* the same as a continuous map $X → Y^I$?

Comment: @k.stm Yes, in the sense that there is a natural (in $X,Y$) one to one correspondence between the two sets $$\mathbf{Top}(X\times I,Y)\longleftrightarrow\mathbf{Top}(X,Y^I)$$ where $Y^I$ is givent the compact open topology, and the correspondence is given by curryfying/decurryfying. The exponential law further claims is that if $X$ is Hausdorff, then this correspondence defines a *homeomorphism* $$Y^{X\times I}\longrightarrow \left(Y^I\right)^X$$ but this part of the theorem you don't need.

Comment: The entry on the nlab is very informative, and there is a very interesting and readable paper by Neil Strickland https://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/homotopy/cgwh.pdf that further exposes a full subcategory of the category of topological spaces where no restrictions need be on any of the spaces for the general exponential law to hold.